# If I push 2 transaction into 1 block, what transaction executed first?

Tags: transactions, mining

So the question is:
Assume that I have specialIndex = 0.
Then I push 2 transactions in a single block:

1. Change specialIndex = 5.
2. is some logic that if specialIndex = 0, you got 500B$.

So I really wonder do you got 500B$, or not? Is blockchain have some logic about this or is it dependent on miner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, as a developer, don't "push" anything in blocks. It's the miners who decide the order of the transactions in a block.

There are ways to influence the block contents (such as Flashbots) but you can't  dictate it: you can, however, revert your Flashbots bundle if your transactions aren't ordered as you wanted.

Once transactions are ordered in a block, they are executed sequentially. So a transaction which is executed after another in the block can depend on the state changes in the other transaction.